# How can I set the timestamps in a Git repository to those of an otherwise-identical repository?

Tags: git, bash, macos, timestamp

I just cloned my git files from a repository onto a new computer. Now they all say that they were modified/created *today*, rather than the actual dates from the old computer.

**How can I "restore" these timestamps in bulk?**

#### Here's what I did:

On my Old Workstation:

- I had a repository at `~/MyWork.git` that I used as a centralized repository: any clones of that repository pulled/pushed from/to that repository.
- I had a local clone of that repository at `~/MyWork`. This was my "working repository".

On my New Workstation:

- I mounted the old hard drive to `/Volumes/OldComputer'
- I copied the centralized repository from my old hard drive to the new:
  `cp /Volumes/OldComputer/Users/Me/MyWork.git ~/MyWorkNew.git`. (It would now be my centralized repository.)
- I created a new folder `mkdir ~/MyWorkNew` on the new computer to be my new "working repository".
- I cloned the new centralized repository to the new working repository: `git clone ~/MyWorkNew.git ~/MyWorkNew/`

I feel like there should be a good way using `git` to do this without just copying everything directly, e.g. `cp -rp /Volumes/OldComputer/Users/Me/MyWork ~/MyWorkNew`...but perhaps I'm wrong?

## Alternative Solution

Short of simply copying all files over, is there a way to copy all timestamps from one repository to another programmatically (#ScriptFu)? The whole directory structure and file names should be the same between the two repositories. It seems it could be done via recursion: "for each `File`, recursively, in `OldDir` and `NewDir`, set the timestamp of `NewDir/File` to that of `OldDir/File`".

Comment: I don't think the problem is in timestamps. Git compares content not timestamps. What do `git status` and `git diff` show?

Comment: Git does not do that. The only thing Git does with file time-stamps is to save work-tree time-stamps in the index, to detect possible modifications. The index is not transferred from one repository to another, though, and in fact you can simply *remove* the index (though you will lose any staged changes) and Git will rebuild it from the work-tree.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to know in what order I created various scripts to know which are the most up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Filesystem timestamps record the last time anything wrote to a file.  In your case, that would be when you copied into them.

If you want the last-committed timestamp for a file, do e.g. `git log -1 --pretty=%cd -- $thefile` or `git blame @ $thefile` to get the last-committed timestamp for each line in it.

Using filesystem timestamps the way you're after is an easy-to-make rookie mistake.  Any system relying on filesystem timestamps to sync other content with your current source will fail. The breakage will generally be of the very worst kind: the results of whatever sort of compilation you do will not reflect the source they were, to all appearances, generated from, because the tools that check those dates will see that the results were generated after the file last changed.  Which, if you do what you're asking for here, will be a lie.

Doing what you're asking for even if only sometimes, only when that's what you'll be using most often, is a recipe for failure.  Keep semantics simple: filesystem timestamp = time-filesystem-written, commit timestamp = time-commit-written, and everything works.

Trust Us: You Really *Really* Don't Want Surprise Semantics.